# How to change the (u)mask in Linux to get a certain permission for a file?

Tags: linux, permissions, umask

What value of **(u)mask** should I use to give the permission `-rwxr-xr--` for the files?

I tried `012` and `022` and didn't work, how do I subtract 666-754?

Comment: By `for the files` do you mean **regular files**?

Comment: Directories are created with 777, and files with 666 modes (except specifics like ssh-keygen). Umask just "removes" bits. So you cannot set 754 on files, just on directories (`umask 0023`).